# Bootstrap Nav-menu broken on specific pages in Safari & IE

Tags: css, safari, navbar

So [my site](http://linestar.ca/climbing-gear/bags/glove-and-sleeve-bags/) works fine in chrome and for the most part on other browsers but in safari and IE the bootstrap nav menu won't collapse and instead spills the menu contents all over the page as seen here:

[image: linestar.ca incorrect header]

Strangely though the nav menu works fine on other pages?:

[image: linestar.ca correct header]

I am at a complete loss as I have:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in my header.

Comment: Hello @UnderQualifiedBoi, I appear to also be getting the mis-styled header in Chrome as well.

Comment: Damn, I am running Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) if that makes a difference? does the issue replicate on other pages or just the one I provided?

Comment: I'm seeing it on Chrome Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit). The issue does not appear on the second link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

For all other pages than the one you have problem with, your menu is inside a `#megaMenu` div.

All other pages DOM tree:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="megaMenu" class="megaMenuContainer"....
```

Page with problem DOM tree:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav...
```

You should investigate why is this happening.

Comment: I have tried to manually code in the mega menu div manually with no avail. if you check the problem page on chrome it has the mega menu div wrapped in a mega menu div with no problems but neither will show on safari/IE